# People Picker field does not show up in Library after save

Tags: infopath, people-picker

I have an existing Infopath 2010 form that works fine.  I added a People Picker field to the form (naming the data field GMPerson), and it works to:
1)  resolve emails into names on the form
2)  save the names
3)  display the names when re-opening the form later

However, the field doesn't appear in the Sharepoint library.  As such, a big view of all the data doesn't ever have the new GMPerson field available.  I can't add the new column to a view.  Where is my new data stored?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All data for InfoPath forms is stored within the form in an XML document. In order for that data to be viewed in a list, you will need to promote that field up as a field when publishing the form to SharePoint. To do this, click File>Info>Form Options> and then click Property Promotion and then select the column you would like to promote as a data field in SharePoint.